# gnome-initial-setup password quality check

Tags: gnome, password

How or where `gnome-initial-setup` checks for quality of password during first user login? I'm trying to customize the image to force users to use longer and more complicated passwords (then 6 as is currently set) but it seems that initial setup has its own way to check the rules - it seems it is ignoring both `pam.d` settings as well as `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` (by browsing the code it seems it is using pwquality lib however).

Edit:
Ok I have found that the account setup on Ubuntu is most probably still handled by ubiquity and not gnome-initial-setup

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the password checks are hardcoded(!) directly into ubiquity. Not very nice solution especially when there is eg. python module for pwquality that can do the proper check and also make it configurable using standard conf file used also by pam.d.

So for a reference if anyone needs to change then there are two functions `human_password_strength` and `password_strength` in the `ubiquity/validation.py` script.